# How to Pass Url parameter in velocity custom web content template

Tags: liferay, velocity

I'm creating a url to other page in my portal and passing a parameter in it, I want to get that parameter in a velocity template on other page, what I'm doing is

```
#set($recordingLinks = [])
#if(!$Event_Recordings.getSiblings().isEmpty())
#foreach ($cur_Event_Recordings in $Event_Recordings.getSiblings())
#set($result = $recordingLinks.add($cur_Event_Recordings.getData()))
#end
#end
```

`<a href="/en/web/guest/event-recordings?recordingLinks=$recordingLinks">Recordings</a>`

how to get "recordingLinks" 
on next page, I'm using

```
#set($links = $request.getParameter("recordingLinks"))
```

in assetpublisher template but no success